# How to mount hard drive

Tags: 12.04, mount

A couple days ago my windows corrupted and I had to mount Ubuntu onto a usb and install it onto a different hard drive that is also connected to the same computer. I have files that I would LOVE to recover off that other computer but if it comes down to it I can get rid of them I would just like to be able to use the hard drive again. However whenever I try to open the hard drive it give me this error

```
"Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/unknown/Gateway: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/unknown/Gateway"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also if you could break down anything to basic info that would be great I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't really know how to do a lot with it right now.

New Message

```
"Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/unknown/Gateway: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda1" "/media/unknown/Gateway"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details."
```

Comment: The FS appears to be corrupted, hopefully recoverably. Have you followed the instructions in the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about that which is part of the problem, I have no access to anything but Ubuntu and I'm not to well acquainted with it.

Comment: Do you have a Windows installation you can boot into where you can plug in and access the hard disk?

Comment: As in do I have any access to windows? If so no.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and try that.

Comment: Alright so I did that and it said NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.

Comment: OK. Can it be mounted now?

Comment: It is not mounting I got a new message though, I edited my Original post with it. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: Have you tried Testdisk yet?

Answer (score 2):

[`ntfsfix`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) is a program to perform limited NTFS checking. While it won't fix all NTFS troubles, it will fix some problems.

First, ensure `ntfs-3g` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Now, run the following to try to repair:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

and let it try to fix things up.

If this fails, download and install [`testdisk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/testdisk). This is a bit more manual but will let you get at any important files that otherwise can't be recovered.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

and run it:

```
sudo testdisk
```

You will then see it scanning volumes and then you can select the correct volume. Follow guidelines for what keys do what at the bottom of the terminal window.

> All commands are in a terminal. When you open the terminal, wait until you see the prompt `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$` before running the command. Since you are in a live CD, you will lose changes when you reboot. Consider installing Ubuntu to a larger external hard disk to have a permanent Ubuntu installation about.
>   When you use `sudo`, it *might* prompt you for the password. On the live media it is `ubuntu`. If you install Ubuntu, it is your user password. When you type it, it will not be seen(not even `****`)